# What version of SQL Server do I need for practice?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

As someone who is new to the DB community, I wanted to reach out and ask which version of SQL server is best for me to practice on. I have access to an abundance of programs through Dreamspark; however, I'm unsure which version I need as there are several of them.

Comment: That very much depends upon what you need to practise...

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 20xx Developer Edition is enough for practice.

SQL Server 20xx Developer Edition lets developers build almost any kind of database application on top of SQL Server. It's licensed for use as a development and test system, not as a production server, and is an ideal choice for people who build and test database applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan on installing SQL server multiples times or in multiple VM's to practice or test the High availability features. SQL server Express edition will do just fine, And it's free too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition if you can.

The simple reason being that the Books Online (which are installed as a local CHM file) are available offline and contain a wealth of information regarding some of the internals of the SQL Server Database Engine.

Things have changed slightly (ok, dramatically) with SQL Server 2012, 2014, and now 2016; but the offline help in SQL Server 2008 R2 is the best IMHO.